# Docker / Buildx Use Multiple Architectures in Different Stages of Multi-Stage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build, buildx, multiarch

So I have issues building my docker container for arm/v6 because a tool I use for dependency management ([Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to be specific) depends on some python wheels that do not exist / are not prebuilt on arm/v6. I only use this tool in one stage to generate a file (requirements.txt) to use with pip in a later stage.
Is it possible to run a single stage on e.g. x86, copy over this generated file and run all of the other stages with arm/v6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With buildkit there are a set of predefined arguments you can use, along with the `--platform` parameter to `FROM` to select a specific platform from a multi-platform image:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM your_base:tag as build

...

FROM your_run:tag as release
COPY --from=build requirements.txt .
...
```

This will use the current build host platform for the build stage, and the target platform for the release stage. There are other build args documented in the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope).

For more details on these features, see [Docker's multi-platform build documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/).